# Choose from open workbooks to paste in copied data

Tags: excel, vba, popup, popupwindow

I am writing an VBA code that should copy a specific range from one workbook into another workbook (that is open). I want to choose this workbook from a popup window that is showing all the open excel workbooks.

What I have to start with is below which is copying the range I want, do not want to specify the workbook (changing every year) or the worksheet (changing every month) more than this. From the `Application.Dialogs(xlDialogActivate).Show` I get a list of active workbooks/aplications (thanks @jkpieterse) and I now want to set this as WB2 so that I can copy past it into my chosen range.

```
Sub GTS_Timesheet()
Dim WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet, RG As Range, WB2 As Workbook
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS = WB.ActiveSheet
Set RG = WS.Range("F10", Range("U" & Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row))
''Set WB2 =
RG.Copy

WB2 = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogActivate).Show

WB2.Worksheets("Paste FRW Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Thanks, and please tell if I need to explain more what I want.

Comment: You could try this: Application.Dialogs(xlDialogActivate).Show but it seems to list add-ins as well, which cannot be activated.

Comment: I do get the list I want.. Do you know how I can set this chosen workbook as WB1?

Comment: The chosen one will be the active workbook, so the code is simply Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook

Answer (score 0):

Once selected the workbook becomes active:

```vb
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogActivate).Show
Set WB2 = ActiveWorkbook
```